# What close reason should I use for interview questions?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I know its age-old but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2380389) is currently in the Close votes review list and I'm not sure which close reason is most appropriate.

A week ago I would have closed this question as "Not constructive" - its not that this question isn't about programming (it clearly is) and its certainly clear what is being asked - the problem it that this sort of question has a countable infinity of different answers, and so everyone feels compelled to post an their own answer that goes "Oooh! Oooh! I know one!".  Also none of these answers are actually useful to anyone unless they get asked that *specific* interview question.

- Are brain-teaser interview questions like this *definitely* off-topic?
- If so what close reason should be used?

Answer (score 2):

To be honest I don't see a problem with that question. If you would take out the interview part and phrase the question like this:

> I'm trying to create a function where  n is a 32 bit signed integer
>   (non complex number)
>
> ```
> f(f(n)) == -n
> ```
>
> Is this possible? If it's not what would be the largest range of
>   numbers I could make this work on?

Would you close this?

Comment: I'd probably vote to close that as "unclear what you're asking" and post a comment "Why on earth do you want to do that? What is the problem you are trying to solve?"

Answer (score 2):

In my Opinion:

I think questions like this should not be closed.

Sometimes they are informative as well as tricky and logical.

I saw several questions asked for interviews which are I didn't even think about that logic.

Also you can cause the interview questions like: what is the difference between ++i and i++ ? etc. Because it is not constructive, the OP didn't show any effort or research for finding the result.

Comment: I'm only talking about brain-teaser interview questions rather than interview questions in general - questions that are about programming but you would never need to actually know the answer to outside of an interview.  I've seen plenty of interviw questions that I would have said are fine e.g. [Interview question: Check if one string is a rotation of other string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553522/interview-question-check-if-one-string-is-a-rotation-of-other-string)

Comment: @Justin: I think there is no need to close them if they are apt for SO (Means not off-topic, or too localized) If the question are asked with any code, facts or shows any research work it shouldn't be closed. Brainteasers are always funny :) !!!